Constructing a matrix $A$ that makes a set of vector mutually $A$-orthogonal

Suppose that we have a system of linearly independent vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible to construct a matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ such that the system $(v_i)_{i=1,\ldots,k}$ is mutually $A$-orthogonal, in the sense that
$$\forall i,j =1,2,\ldots,k, i \ne j, \quad \langle v_i, Av_j \rangle = 0? $$

This question was motivated by the fact that given a matrix $A$ and a linear subspace $L$, we can construct a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ of $L$ such that the system $(v_i)_{i=1,\ldots,k}$ is mutually $A$-orthogonal. I was wondering if the reverse situation could happen, but found no way to construct it. The proof for the fact I mentioned here can be found in, for instance, [1, Lemma 1]
I would greatly appreciate any hints/comments you may have. Thank you for your time.
References:
[1] Maddocks, J.H., 1985. Restricted quadratic forms and their application to bifurcation and stability in constrained variational principles. SIAM journal on mathematical analysis, 16(1), pp.47-68.

Complete the set to a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $V$ be the matrix whose columns are these vectors. Then put $A=(V^{-1})^TV^{-1}$.

More abstractly: Let $V = \mathbb R^n$. Complete to a basis $v_i$. Form the dual basis $v^i\in V^$. Let $A' : V \to V^$ be defined by $A'(v_i) = v^i$ and let $\sharp : V^* \to V$ be the inverse of the map $v \mapsto \langle v,{-}\rangle$. Then take $A = \sharp\circ A'$.
